# DjangoCMS ImageField - browsing from uploaded media?

Tags: django-forms, django-cms

I have written a plugin for my DjangoCMS site, part of which is displaying a picture uploaded during configuration.

I can see the pictures stored in the servers Media folder. I want for the user to be able to browse from the already uploaded images in addition to being able to select their own for upload.

I have no idea where to start with this!

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that does exactly that: https://github.com/stefanfoulis/cmsplugin-filer